# Value too great for base (error token is "0925")

Tags: bash, ubuntu, octal

I have the following logic in my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
local_time=$(date +%H%M)

if (( ( local_time > 1430  && local_time < 2230 ) || ( local_time > 0300 && local_time < 0430 ) )); then
 # do something
fi
```

Every now and then, I get the error specified in the title (any time above `08xx` appears to trigger the error).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I am running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

**[Edit]**

I modified the script as suggested by SiegeX, and now, I am getting the error: `[: 10#0910: integer expression expected`.

Any help?

Answer (score 17):

`bash` is treating your numbers as **octal** because of the leading zero

#### From `man bash`

> Constants with a leading 0 are
>   interpreted as octal numbers.  A
>   leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal.
>          Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where base is a decimal
>   number between 2 and 64 represent-
>          ing  the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base.  If base# is
>   omitted, then base 10 is used.

To fix it, specify the base-10 prefix

```
#!/bin/bash
local_time="10#$(date +%H%M)"

if (( ( local_time > 1430  && local_time < 2230 ) || ( local_time > 0300 && local_time < 0430 ) )); then
 # do something
fi
```

Comment: I modified my script as you suggested, and run it a few minutes ago, and I received the following error: [: 10#0910: integer expression expected

Comment: @oompah: hmm, no error when I run it here or on ideone as listed [HERE](http://ideone.com/EaR6j).  What version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: my bash version details are: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: @oompa: I don't know what to tell you.  Did you *copy & paste* my code exactly and try to run it? Replace `# do something` with a simple `echo foo` to make sure its not the code you didn't paste

Comment: Thanks. I have used `"10$f"` for a `$f` variable and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Following the advice from [this blog](http://programming.has.no.com/2008/07/31/shell-gotcha-08-value-too-great-for-base/), this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
local_time=`date +%H%M`
local_time="$(( 10#$local_time ))"

if (( ( local_time > 1430  && local_time < 2230 ) || ( local_time > 0300 && local_time < 0430 ) )); then
    echo "it is time!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solving the issue within the conditional test

One may be forced to keep the variable as it is for a variety of reasons (e.g. file naming issues). If this is the case, solve the issue *within* the conditional test **by explicitly specifying base** `10#`:

```
#!/bin/bash
local_time=$(date +%H%M)

if (( ( 10#${local_time} > 1430  && 10#${local_time} < 2230 ) || ( 10#${local_time} > 0300 && 10#${local_time} < 0430 ) )); then
 # do something
fi
```